# VB - How to initialise a character array?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do it as below with runtime error 91 - *Object variable not set*

```
Dim columns(6) As Characters
Dim cColCount As Integer
Dim sColCount As Integer


columns(0) = A
columns(1) = B
columns(2) = C
columns(3) = D
columns(4) = E
columns(5) = F
```

I'm new to VB and all online resources only show examples of Integer and some string arrays. Unfortunately, like `New Integer()`, there seems to be nothing for a character array.

What should be my approach for a character array?

Comment: `Dim columns(6) As String` and `columns(0) = "A"`

Comment: Are you using VB6 or VBA?

Comment: @braX VB6, macro in Excel 2007

Comment: Well if you are using VB in Excel, then you are using VBA. Knowing that might help you find the right tutorials.

Comment: Oh I did not know that! Thanks a lot for the info

Comment: [Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columns) is a property of the range object. Try e.g. `Dim Cols(0 To 5) As String: Cols(0) ="A"... Cols(5) = "F"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA thinks that `Characters` is the Characters object for a range.  See [Characters object (Excel) Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters)

`Dim columns(6) As Characters` defines an array but not the objects in each element.  If you had created your own class called Characters then you could do something like this for each element

```
Set columns(0) = New Characters
```

But at the moment that will also produce an error ("Invalid use of New keyword")

The real problem is understanding that a set of "characters" is called a String in VBA (and many other languages).
So as @braX has pointed out, you need to use `Dim columns(6) As String`. Because String is built in to VBA you don't need to "initialise" each instance in the array.

Your next problem is understanding how strings are represented in VBA and many many other languages. You can't just stick an `A` out there and hope that Excel understands you mean the letter "A". In VBA we surround strings with double-quotation marks so `columns(0) = "A"` would be ok.

Alternatively you would have to define the Variable A e.g. `Dim A as String` and assign it a value e.g. `A = "A"`

Here are a couple of other links to help you on your journey

[Language Reference for VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference)

[Excel VBA Programming for complete beginners](https://www.homeandlearn.org/index.html)